# I can't send a POST request using my browser?

Tags: spring-boot, http, spring-mvc, post, postman

I am working on an application using Spring Boot MVC and I have a login page and whenever I input data on the forms using chrome my browser doesn't redirect me to the page I've specified in my Controler class but instead It sends a GET request where it should be sending a POST request. This is my controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class loginController {
private final AuthService authService;

public loginController(AuthService authService) {
this.authService = authService;
}

 @GetMapping
  public String returnLogIn() {
  return "login";
  }

@PostMapping
public String login(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password, Model model) {

User user = null;
try {
    user = this.authService.login(username, password);
    model.addAttribute("User", user);
    return "redirect:/home";
} catch (InvalidArgumentsException exception) {

    model.addAttribute("hasError", true);
    model.addAttribute("error", exception.getMessage());
    return "login";
}
```

}
}
As you see if the login is successful then I should be redirected to the home page but It doesn't happen I get redirected to the login page again and all that changes is the URL in it the parameters I've given are appended. But when I use POSTMAN everything works just fine a POST request is sent and I get redirected to the /home page just like I've specified it in my Controller class. But I don't know why this wont happen when I use chrome. Having to use POSTMAN everytime I do a small change is really time-consuming. Also this is the HTML form

```
<form id="form-id"  th:action="@{/login}" th:method="post">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username"  aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                       placeholder="User Name">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <!-- TODO use hasError set it in the model -->
            <div th:if="${hasError}">
            <span class="error text-danger" th:text="${error}"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-color px-5 mb-5 w-100 btn btn-dark" >Login</button></div>
            </form>
```

I don't think there is something wrong with my code since everything works fine when I use POSTMAN but I really don't know why It wont work when I use my browser. Javascript is enabled in my browser I really don't know what seems to be the issue. I also tried mapping the POST request to a different URL but still I get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also believe that your code sample has no problem because if there is a problem it should not respond correctly from POSTMAN,Unless you have configured the application  server and restricted requests from the browsers.
The suggestion I can give you is to monitor requests when sending a request using tools like Fiddler (Fiddler is a powerful web debugging proxy),etc.. ,to see if both requests send the same parameters to server .

Comment: Can you please explain in more details what I am supposed to do with Fiddler?

Comment: Use to debug requests sent from Chrome and Postman. By doing this, you will find that both requests are sent to the same server with the same specifications or are different.